# Grunt.js with grunt-styleguide and compass

Tags: gruntjs

Does anybody use Grunt.js+grunt-styleguide to generate a Styling Guide?

I have problems with it. I can generate all files, but "style.css" is empty!

I use the standard

```
yo webapp
```

template and a modified standard grunt-styleguide task

```
    styleguide: {
        options: {
            framework: {
                name: 'kss'
                options: {
                    'preprocessor': 'scss'
                }
            }
        },
        all: {
            files: [{
                '<%= config.dist %>/styleguide': '<%= config.app %>/styles/**/*.scss'
            }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Does your KSS throw errors like `error: file to import not found or unreadable: "compass"`? That's wat mine does :(